# Getting path to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, path, image

everybody!

I know, that probably the question was asked many times, but anyway..

The problem is:

I have a solution with 2 projects (C# Class Library and Web-project).
In class library project I've overriden a text box control, so it has built-in validations. On local server everything works nice, but when I upload published project, the problems begin.

Here's the code:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("~/images/alert.png")]
    public string AlertImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/alert.png");
            return GetPropertyValue<string>("AlertImageUrl", path);
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("AlertImageUrl", value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.Attributes["onfocus"] = "var objs = this.parentNode.childNodes; for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {if (objs[i].id == 'imgAlert') { objs[i].style.display = 'none'; } }";
        writer.WriteFullBeginTag("span");
        base.Render(writer);
        if (!_validator.IsValid)
        {
            writer.WriteBeginTag("img");
            writer.WriteAttribute("id", "imgAlert");
            writer.WriteAttribute("runat", "server");
            writer.WriteAttribute("style", "left: -20px; top: 3px;");
            writer.WriteAttribute("src", AlertImageUrl);
            writer.WriteEndTag("img");
        }
        writer.WriteEndTag("span");
    }
```

Image is located in App_Themes/Theme_name/images/alert.png
How to get AlertImageUrl correctly? Strange, if I manually set  it returns correct path, but WriteAttribute - no..

Any help is appreciated, 
Regards, Maris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ResolveClientUrl` method instead of the `Server.MapPath`

Comment: carefully read documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx `A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.`